# Android Studio Manifest Merger failed with multiple error

Tags: android, firebase, android-manifest

after I finish making all the SDK settings for Android and try to compile it gives me the error of “Manifest merger failed with multiple errors”. I have added below dependency lib in gradle file. I'm trying to solve this issue from last 2 days but no any success

- AndroidStudio 3.4
- Kotlin 1.3.21
- Gradle 5.4.1-all

Gradle:

```
dependencies {

    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:28.0.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'

    implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3'
    implementation 'com.wang.avi:library:2.1.3'
    implementation 'com.sothree.slidinguppanel:library:3.3.1'
    implementation 'com.squareup:seismic:1.0.2'
    implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.7.0'
    implementation 'jp.wasabeef:blurry:2.1.0'
    implementation 'com.nshmura:snappysmoothscroller:1.0.0'
    implementation 'com.simplecityapps:recyclerview-fastscroll:1.0.16'
    implementation 'org.jsoup:jsoup:1.9.2'
    implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp:2.7.5'
    implementation 'com.getkeepsafe.taptargetview:taptargetview:1.9.1'
    implementation 'com.sackcentury:shinebutton:0.1.7'
    implementation project(':dialogs')
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-ads:17.1.3'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.7'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:16.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:17.3.4'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:16.0.6'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-invites:16.1.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:16.0.5'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-config:16.3.0'
    implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.5'

    implementation 'com.theartofdev.edmodo:android-image-cropper:2.6.0'

    implementation 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:8.8.1'
    kapt 'com.jakewharton:butterknife-compiler:8.8.1'

    implementation 'com.github.takahirom.downloadable.calligraphy:downloadable-calligraphy:0.1.3'

    implementation 'com.google.android:flexbox:1.0.0'

    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"

    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.5.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.5.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:3.9.1'
    implementation 'com.onesignal:OneSignal:[3.9.1, 3.99.99]'
}
```

I have used the above dependency in my project, but some of the libraries are a conflict with each other.

Comment: Could you please post your manifest file ..

Comment: `“Manifest merger failed with multiple errors”`,
please attach your build error log too.

Answer (score 0):

you can add one line below to XML Elements for telling to manifest merger your app manifest is highest priority manifest in app 
`tools:node="merge`

please read [this article](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/manifest-merge#merge_rule_markers)  for more information

hope this help